# How to enable flutter to view harder APIs which ask for different variables to gain access to them?

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart

[How do you load such an API into flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO8p2.png)

For example, I wish to create something that can get the traffic update but the dataMall set only gives you the variables in terms of python and not .dart or .java.

This is the code that I wrote down:

```
  void getData() async {
    http.Response response= await http.get(
        'http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/BusArrivalv2?BusStopCode=83139');
    print(response.body);
  }
```

This is the code that they gave if you coded it in python

```
import urllib
from urlparse import urlparse
import httplib2 as http #External library
if __name__=="__main__":
 #Authentication parameters
 headers = { 'AccountKey' : 'ACCOUNT_KEY',
 'accept' : 'application/json'} #this is by default

 #API parameters
 uri = 'http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/' #Resource URL
 path = '/ltaodataservice/BusRoutes?'
 #Build query string & specify type of API call
 target = urlparse(uri + path)
 print target.geturl()
 method = 'GET'
 body = ''

 #Get handle to http
 h = http.Http()
 #Obtain results
 response, content = h.request(
 target.geturl(),
 method,
 body,
 headers)
 #Parse JSON to print
 jsonObj = json.loads(content)
 print json.dumps(jsonObj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
 #Save result to file
 with open("bus_routes.json","w") as outfile:
 #Saving jsonObj["d"]
 json.dump(jsonObj, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4,
ensure_ascii=False)
```

[LTA DataMall(go over to Bus timings) for example](https://www.mytransport.sg/content/dam/datamall/datasets/LTA_DataMall_API_User_Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation of `http` package [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/get.html) the `get` function has a named argument `headers`

Also, under section **1. MAKING API CALLS** in the pdf you provided it says

*Enter your AccountKey under Headers*.

The default response body will be in JSON. You can change this by adding `accept: 'application/atom+xml'` in `headers`. This is optional.

The sample code provided in pdf is in python but the response you get will be in JSON.

So all you need is

```
void getData() async {
    http.Response response= await http.get('http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/BusArrivalv2?BusStopCode=83139', headers: {
      'AccountKey': 'YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY'
    });
    print(response.body);
  }
```

and then you can parse the response body. [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) is a sample from the Flutter website.

Comment: Oh thanks :)). I have another question however, for example; if i want to return a location to the API is it possible or does it use the same format as shown above;  say to find out which bus stop is nearest to the said user:

Comment: You'll need a `POST` request if you want to give some data to API.  But if it returns some information based on the value sent by you, it will be `GET` request. So it looks like `get` request here. Better check out the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the AccountKey in your request's header.

```
return http.get('http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/BusArrivalv2?BusStopCode=83139', headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'AccountKey': 'YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY'
});
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how this answer will solve the problem, instead of posting code-only answer.